# Why does shared state degrade performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I've been working under the share-nothing principle of concurrent programming. Essentially, all my worker threads have immutable read-only copies of the same state which is never shared between them (*even by reference*). Generally speaking, this has worked really well.

Now, someone has introduced a no-lock singleton cache (*e.g. a static dictionary*) that all the threads are accessing concurrently. Since the dictionary is never altered after startup there are no locks. There haven't been any Thread-Safety issues, but now there is a performance degradation.

The question is... since there are no locks why does the introduction of this singleton create a performance hit? What exactly is going on under the covers that could explain this?

To confirm, accessing this new singleton is the only change and I can reliably recreate this simply by commenting out the call to the cache.

Comment: Have you pointed a profiler at the code?

Comment: Profiling is unlikely to answer this question unless you're profiling the CLR and possibly the windows kernel (not an easy task for the average programmer).

Comment: Not yet, although I plan too... I guess the larger question in my mind is how is read-only state shared between threads a bad thing? I guess it never occured to me to think about this in the context of the "share-nothing" principle. When locking is concerned this makes sense, or even variable modification and their impacts on L2 Cache performance which also makes sense. But immutable read-only shared state... I guess I never thought to work through that in the past. :-P

Comment: @JoeGeeky Are you absolutely sure it is because it is a shared dictionary, as opposed to non-shared dictionaries? I mean, by commenting out the call the code will execute faster, irregardless. Are you saying that everything is faster when each thread has it's *own* dictionary?

Comment: @Max Yes, if I clone the dictionary and give each thread its own copy things move faster, although the load on memory is higher; but that's expected.

Comment: @JoeGeeky Alrighty then, I guess the only thing to do for me here is +1 and favoriting! It seems weird since they are both at the same level of indirection after all, and should fit in processor cache anyway, etc...

Comment: How have you indicated to the CLR that the cache and its contents are immutable?  Can you make it writable and see if the problem gets worse?

Comment: @Max That is what I would have thought. Then again, I have always heard that singletons were evil and haven't connected the dots between the no-sharing and singletons-are-evil principles. I'm assuming there is some kind indirect syncronization that is occuring, although typing that at this point just feels wrong. Also, I've ruled out some kind of 'false sharing' issue since nothing is being updated/changed with any of the shared data.

Comment: @TMN Good question. The immutability is implicit, I'm sure the state is never changing nor is the dictionary being modified beyond the initial fill. The process in this area is simple... When the process starts it populates the cache from a database and then spawns all the worker threads which only read/lookup the state. This seems to be a classic write-once read-many scenario.

Comment: Do you have threads running on multiple cores?  Since cores have their own cache, keeping them synced could account for the extra overhead.  Operating systems aren't always smart enough to know you intend data to be immutable.

Comment: In the dev environment this is an 8 core machine with 8 worker threads. In terms of the sync, the state never changes and there are no explicit locking, so what would be sync'd. I'm not disagreeing, just not understanding.

Comment: Since we do not even have a theory yet as to what is wrong, let me ask this (shamelessly shotgunning) question: how does performance get affected if you try using a ConcurrentDictionary instead of a plain Dictionary?

Comment: FWIT I spawned a couple threads and ran some timers. I instantiated a class, singleton, lockedSingleton, and dict<string,string>. After the first instantiation of each, consecutive runs took about 2000ns for any given object. The dictionary ran 2x slower,might be caused by constructor code...it is slower than lock by itself. Considering all the GC, OS handling of thread queue's and other overhead...not sure one can truly answer this question. But, from my results I don't believe the issue has to do with Singletons. Not if it's implemented like on MSDN.Excludes compiler optimizations.

Comment: @MikeNakis Although I haven't tested this for this issue, my tests in the past have shown that the `ConcurrentDictionary`; and other similar .NET 4.0 ConcurrentX constructs; perform very well when there is higher sustained loads where read & write thread-safety is a concern and I use them frequently. Given the nature of how it works it should be slower; albeit slightly; then a read-only dictionary with no locks at all. With that said, its worth a try.

Comment: @JoeGeeky - another thought: does using the cache add a level of indirection?  If frequently accessed, chasing down an extra pointer deref (or MSIL equiv) could add some time over a local less-indirect copy.

Comment: Any news on that front, JoeGeeky?

Comment: No smoking gun yet... sdg's comment regarding pointer deref may have merit but I am having trouble testing that. Also, all the L2 cache testing didn't uncover anything. (*Boggle* :-P)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that the immutable state shares a cache-line with something mutable. In this case, a change to the nearby mutable state *might* have the effect of forcing a resynch of this cache line across cores, which could slow down performance.

Comment: This sounds like a `false sharing` scenario that your describing. To isolate that I'll need to profile L2 Cache. Unfortunetally, these are reference types so adding buffer space will not be an option if this is actually what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

I would make sure that the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods of the objects you use as keys to the dictionary do not have any unexpected non-threading-friendly side-effects. Profiling would greatly help here.

If by any chance your keys are strings, then perhaps there you have it: rumor has it that strings behave like immutable objects but for the sake of certain optimizations they are internally implemented in a mutable fashion, with everything that this entails with respect to multithreading.

I would try passing the dictionary to the threads that use it as a regular reference instead of a singleton to see whether the problem lies with the sharedness or with the singletonness of the dictionary. (Eliminating the possible causes.)

I would also try with a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of a regular `Dictionary` just in case its use yields some surprising results.  There are lots of things to be speculated about the problem at hand if a `ConcurrentDictionary` turns out to perform much better or much worse than your regular `Dictionary`.

If none of the above points to the problem, then I would guess that the degraded performance is caused by some weird sort of contention between the garbage-collecting thread and the rest of your threads, as the garbage-collector is trying to figure out whether the objects in your dictionary need to be disposed or not, while they are being accessed by your threads.